# access token fanpage for dashboard

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-fql, facebook-opengraph, facebook-page

I want to get access to my `fanpage` to show insights of the page on another website as a dashboard on a TV in our company.

1. How can I get a Access Token? I´ve already tried it in developer-facebook section. But I only get the Access Token for my personal profile.
2. Do the Access Token expire?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook documentation already has a [step-by-step tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/login-as-page/) for this.

Mainly, you need:

1. `manage_pages` permission
2. [extend your user access token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/extending-tokens/)
3. get a page access token with the above user token (the generated page token will not expire)
4. You also need the `read_insights` permission for your specific case

Comment: I have tried this: get access token with: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me/accounts  Then i request a token with extended permissions (all checkboxes incl. offline...) Is there any simple example including javascript sdk login to call the api with fql?

Comment: Using fql in the Javascript sdk is straight forward, here's an [example](http://www.fbrell.com/saved/276cc1ede99639335b9400d76ab9706d).